# Api Rest Xamarin forms c#

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms, lumen

Tengo mi api rest creada en lumen (PHP) y esta en mi hosting MySQL, tengo mi tabla usuarios con los campos ID, DNI,Nombre, Cargo, updated_at y created_at, cuando hago insercion por POSTMAN me sale bien (obviamente solo pongo DNI, Nombre y Cargo ya que lo demas se genera automaticamente).
El problema esta en mi VS que cuando lo mando para que haga el insert me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***ESTE ES MI CODIGO EN C# ***

ESTA ES MI CLASE:

```
public class Usuarios
{
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public string DNI { get; set; }
    public string Nombres { get; set; }        
    public string Cargo { get; set; }      
}
```

ESTE ES MI SERVICIO REST:

```
HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
    public async Task<int> AddTodoItemAsync(Usuarios usuarios)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usuarios);
        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client2.PostAsync("http://www.xxxxxxx.com/public/api/userNew", content);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        return result;
    }
```

EVENTO CLIC DE MI BOTON AL DAR "REGISTRAR"

```
RestService dataService;
async void btn_NewUser(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdni.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtnombres.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtcargo.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Atencion","POR FAVOR LLENAR TODOS LOS CAMPOS","Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            Usuarios newUser = new Usuarios
            {
                DNI = txtdni.Text.Trim(),
                Nombres = txtnombres.Text.Trim(),
                Cargo = txtcargo.Text.Trim()                   
            };
            await dataService.AddTodoItemAsync(newUser);
        }
```

Comment: dataService es null. nunca lo inicializaste. Salvo que sea una clase estatica, ese seria tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo.